# ng-repeat in AngularJS not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

Here is a simple Select done in Angular

```
<select ng-model="myCar">
    <option ng-repeat="car in cars" value="{{car}}">{{car}}</option>
</select>
```

I have the following in my scope in angular.js

```
$scope.cars = ["Toyota", "Ford", "Rolls"];
```

why isn't the options showing up, instead I get {{car}}

Comment: Where did you add cars in $scope, can you make a fiddle?

Comment: If you are getting {{car}}, I think the js file or controller is not properly hooked up. Could you please see console if there are any errors? You can also try $scope.test = 'Hello world' in controller and {{test}} in template to ensure that controller is hooked up properly

Comment: This is working. Let me share you my codepen Link : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGgaWE

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
<select ng-model="myCar" ng-options = "car for car in cars" ng-init="myCar = 'Rolls'">

</select>
```

or this

```
<select ng-model="myCar" ng-init="myCar = 'Rolls'">
        <option ng-repeat="car in cars" value={{car}}>{{car}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your's code is working fine. Only the default value isn't selected, so at the beginning it shows blank.
Refer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/t30jvsan/).

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
    <select ng-model="myCar">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option ng-repeat="car in cars" value="{{car}}">{{car}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function ($scope) {
    $scope.cars = ["Toyota", "Ford", "Rolls"];
});
```